# What type of jack is the flight interphone on transport category aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-systems, ground-operations, boeing-777, headset

Recently became an A&P and part of my job is to be on the ground communicating to the pilots during push backs. Started shopping for a headset and have seen various ones with different adapters and jacks. What size jack would work on the flight interphone  on e.g. a B777?

Comment: Doesn't your employer offer the equipment needed to do your job? While headsets admittedly are a somewhat personally tailored item (a model that works well for one person might not work so well for another), I would certainly expect an employer to at least offer a selection of choices, complete with whatever adapters are needed to connect to the aircraft.

Comment: Also, even if it's a relatively simple item, I would expect *anything* connected to an aircraft, and used in a safety-sensitive situation to require a large number of certifications, not just "let's buy something off Amazon...".

Comment: The Jacks in the cockpit vary from airline to airline, and the impedance of pilot headsets vary as most military radios use very low impedance and most civilian are high impedance, so a lot of used items need to be checked for exact model numbers. for pilots we commonly have dual plug, 6-pin, and single plug [aka helicopter]
But some headsets have changeable cords.

Answer (score 2):

The jack on every commercial airliner from Boeing and Airbus is a single plug U/174 type (aka helicopter).

That holds true as long as we speak of the external jacks used for the flight interphone and service interphone. In the cockpit this is a different beast. You'll find a lot of variation:

- classic two-plug
- U/174 (aka helicopter, impedance must be matched, no power to headset)
- XLR-5 (passes power to headset, often found in Boeing aircraft)
- NeutriCON (passes power to headset, often found in Airbus aircraft)
- LEMO (passes power to headset, used mainly by Bose)

What you'll find in the cockpit mainly depends on what the buyer ordered. Boeing standard in their newer aircraft is the classic two-plug and a XLR-5 side by side (e.g. B747-8, B787, not sure about the B777). As an example, the company AvtechTyee supplies their 5775 series jack panel for the B787 First Officers side.